# Dotnet highcharts not working (Missing assembly)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Hello im using MVC3 (Visual studio express 2012)

I follow the instructions on this side;
http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

I have made a new controller called TestHSController with a corresponding view.

The problem is that when im trying to run the code;

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Data = new Data(new object[] { 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 })
            });

        return View(chart);
    }
```

The Xaxis, Series and Data are marked in blue as if im missing an assembly, i have added the DotNet.Highcharts as a reference and in my _Layout i have added the lines;

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
```

The files are in the repective places.

Any input would be appriciated.

Comment: any error message from your browser devTools?

Comment: i cant even build it. Its missing the assambly for XAxis, Series and Data

Comment: Do i need to do something more then just add the highcharts to reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following to your controller class

```
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options; // for XAxis and Series
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers; // for Data
```

If still it does not build, there is another problem about your project.

Comment: Doh! Long time ago i felt this stupid. Thank you very much. Now you have saved me two days in a row, i hope that i can avoid the hattrick ;)

Comment: I'm glad, I could help. Sometimes, you should not think complex :)